# Facebook API 2.x — Undocumented requirements to use read_stream

Tags: facebook-graph-api, review

I just got my read_stream request denied after completing a full Facebook app (weeks of hard work and a potentially very unhappy client).

Their reason:

`The read_stream permission is only approved for apps that let people use Facebook on platforms or devices that don’t have a Facebook app. If you're building an app on Android, iOS, Web or Desktop, for example, you won't be approved for this permission.`

THEY DON'T MENTION THIS ANYWHERE!

I'm using the permission in a web app to get some fun info about the user's friends in order to present a test result like "Your friend X posts the most pictures" (based on the last 400 posts in the user's feed).

Is there any way to get an approval? Or do you have a different creative solution to my problem?

The data I'm getting using the read_stream permission as of now is:
1 - posts with location (to see who's checking in abroad most often)
2 - posts with links (to see who posts the most links)
3 - how many likes does my friend's posts get
4 - who is making many posts, but I never like the posts

VERY grateful for any help. :)

Comment: This does indeed not seem to be explicitly mentioned as of now; however https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1 mentiones “common usages” for permissions, so it might be a good idea to take that as a point of reference, and try to clear up any doubt beforehand by asking in the Facebook Developer Group on FB. And from reading in that group I can also tell you, that there is little to no chance that you will get that permission approved – _“only approved for apps that let people use Facebook on platforms or devices that don’t have a Facebook app”_ is meant literally.

Comment: I got the same denied answer. What is strange is that I can see posts from a facebook page and don't need read_stream, but groups do require this for some odd reason. Please tell me what device or platform won't have a facebook app already available. Can't be a computer, phone or tablet so what is left?